# Unused global variable in embedded system

Tags: embedded

when I define a Global(ROM & RAM) variable but never used in my code anywhere, how to figure out those variables while compilation.
currently, I am working with green hills compiler.Is there any chance to find the unused global variables.

Comment: they should be in .data unless declared as constants then they would be in .text or .rodata.  did you examine the binary?

Comment: The .map file generated by the linker should identify the address of global variables.  However, unused variables and functions might be stripped from the executable by the linker.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally see this in the Linker Map file that is generated.
As quoted from [a manual](http://www.ece.ualberta.ca/~cmpe490/documents/ghs/build_arm.pdf)  I could find: (page 207)

> **Map File Generation**
>   Controls the generation of a map file. Permitted settings for this option are:
>   • **Generate Default Map File (-map)** — [default]
>   Creates a map file with the name of the object file plus a .map extension.
>   • **Generate User-Specified Map File (-map=filename)** —
>     Creates a map file with the specified filename.
>   • **Suppress Map(-nomap)**

You can feed these options using the additional arguments in your project, and it will create a file reporting everything there is to know about locations and sizes of your firmware.

The file will be in "readable" text in the output directory with `.map` extension.
You can look for **removed symbols**, or **unused symbols**.

*Note that it is the default behavior is to create a map file.*

One handy feature that is often available in the linker is the creation of the [callgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph). You can use it easily see what functions depends on each other. And more importantly, it reports per function what the worst case **predictable** stack usage could be.
It normally does not predict stack usage caused by interrupts.